# Can't post all three text fields to text document?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a website for a college assignment and i'm having issues getting my three text fields to submit to my text document. I managed to get it to send the first one over by simply putting `$_POST['des1']` and sure enough it worked perfectly. However, when I attempt to make it send over all three it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
<?php
    $myFile=fopen("Observation.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $_POST['des1'], $_POST['act1'], $_POST['date1']."\r\n");
    fclose($myFile);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `fwrite()` only takes a max of 3 arguments, but only 2 are necessary.

If you want to write it to the file, the second argument has to be the only text being written to that file.

You currently have a few `,` separating the current fields, which `fwrite` will treat like more arguments and get confused.

It needs to be something like this:

```
$string = $_POST['des1'].$_POST['act1'].$_POST['date1']."\r\n";

fwrite($myFile, $string);
```

Comment: Okay so I tried it like this `$content = $_POST['des1'].$_POST['act1'].$_POST['date1']."\r\n";
 
 $myFile=fopen("Observation.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
 fwrite($myFile, $content);
 fclose($myFile);` and I get this error Wrong parameter count for fwrite() in /home3/hutch/public_html/Murphy/Observation.php on line 14 which is after `$content = $_POST['des1'].$_POST['act1'].$_POST['date1']."\r\n";` and that line is empty?

Comment: Glad I could help @MatthewHutchings